# MS Excel 2007 file's getting corrupt?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, file-corruption

I am using MS Excel 2007 to store my data. I also have a backup copy in my server, but last time when i saved the file it did, but now it is showing 0 KB, and when trying to open the file it is showing file is corrupt. Both files are having the same problem. Is there any way to recover that file?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there is an option in MS Office that saves a backup file. For this to be of use to you, it must be enabled which I don't think it is by default, also, if you saved twice while your file was in a corrupted state then it will have been hosed as well. I'll check when I'm back on a Windows box.

Comment: yeah! that was not enabled, so is there any way??

Comment: To enable or disable that http://www.recipester.org/solution-office-2007-disable-auto-backup.html

Comment: Not that I know of. maybe someone else?